# Why does std::map not always allow a compatible type as its key type?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, standards

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string_view key = "hello";      
    map<string, int, less<>> coll;
    coll.find(key); // ok
    coll[key] = 0;  // !!! error ???
}
```

The key type is `std::string`, the compatible type is `std::string_view`. Since C++14, `std::map::find` allows a compatible key to be used; so `coll.find(key);` is ok.

However, **why isn't** `coll[key] = 0;` **ok too?**

Comment: Because [] didn't get more overloads in 14, unlike find...?

Comment: `operator[]` also inserts when not found

Comment: @deviantfan, Why not to overload []?

Comment: @Danh This may be not the problem when argument is convertible to key_type.

Comment: @Orient This question is ill-written, what he want to ask is why associated doesn't have Heterogeneous comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rationale behind was described in [N3465](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3465.pdf).

> Conceptually, the extension consists in replacing the original formulation based on strict weak orderings with one relying on the notion of sequence partitioning, as first proposed by David Abrahams. Unfortunately, this extension process has not been carried out for the lookup operations of associative containers, which are still formulated in terms of strict weak orderings and thus do not allow for heterogeneous
>   comparison.

Take this example from N3465, and modify its a bit:

```
struct name_entry
{
    std::string family_name;
    std::string given_name;
};
auto as_tuple(const name_entry& e)
{
     return std::tie(e.family_name, e.given_name);
}
bool operator<(const name_entry& x, const name_entry& y)
{
    return as_tuple(x) < as_tuple(y);
}
bool operator<(const name_entry& x, const std::string& y) 
{
    return x.family_name<y;
}
bool operator<(const std::string& x, const name_entry& y) 
{
    return x<y.family_name;
}
int main()
{
    std::set<name_entry, std::less<>> names;
}
```

Heterogeneous comparison was invented to duel with find the contained object that satisfied partial comparison like find someone has a given surname.

`operator[]`, in other hand, will construct a `value_type` if the `key` is not found, it's necessary to apply strict weak ordering with this operation, thus cannt be applied with heterogeneous comparison

Comment: I'm guessing those `operator()` are supposed to be `operator<`? Anyway, sane `operator<` implementation instead of doing comparisons manually: `return std::tie(x.family_name, x.given_name) < std::tie(y.family_name, y.given_name);`

Comment: @ildjarn yes, I copied from that paper with not much change. Will edit now. Regarding `std::tie` I know it's better, like I said, I copied from that paper

Answer (score 4):

`coll.find(key)` only requires `key` to be *comparable* with the actual key type, and `std::string_view` is comparable with `std::string`. However, in order to be able to insert `key` into `coll`, `key` needs to be *convertible* to `std::string`, which it is not (implicitly, anyway).

Comment: I believe OP is asking why `find` was overloaded to deduce a type and `operator[]` wasn't extended the same way, not for an explanation of the error